# Laravel routing with Closures and Names

Tags: php, laravel, closures

I'm curious, because I can't find much in the way of documentation on this - How would I name a route if I also want to call a closure?

I've found how I can call a controller function, but not how to name the route.

Named Route:

`Route::get( '{foo}', ['as' => 'foo.home', 'uses' => 'FooController@home'] );`

Closure Route w/ controller call:

```
Route::get( '{foo}', function() {
    $fooController = $app->make('FooController');
    return $fooController->callAction('home', $parameters = array());
});
```

But I can't find how to incorporate the name of the route into the second example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array with `name` and `uses` as well:

```
Route::get('{foo}', array('name' => 'foo.home', 'uses' => function(){
    $fooController = $app->make('FooController');
    return $fooController->callAction('home', $parameters = array());
}));
```

It also works without `uses` (Laravel recognizes the type `Closure`)

```
Route::get('{foo}', array('name' => 'foo.home', function(){
    $fooController = $app->make('FooController');
    return $fooController->callAction('home', $parameters = array());
}));
```

Comment: So passing the closure as part of the array is perfectly acceptable? That's awesome!

Comment: Yes it is. It's even used [in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) (e.g. under *Attaching A Filter To A Route*)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is call it as class

```php
Route::get( '{foo}', function() {
  return (new $fooController)->homeMethod($parameters);
})->name('foohome');;
```